VirtualBox Guest Additions can't install (Windows Host)
I recently updated my VirtualBox on a Windows host and it seems to have broken my display settings. I tried messing with the settings but with no luck, so I uninstalled it and installed version 7.1.4. Now when I try installing the Guest Additions, I get a verr_broken_pipe error for component GuestSessionWrap. The interface is IGuestSession if that helps.
I tried manually remounting the guest additions which failed, then I removed the iso from Storage and left it empty. I started the VM and inserted the Guest Additions iso and tried updating, but I get the same results.
What else should I do to resolve this?

You only add to reinstall the guest additions of the same version virtualbox what updated to.

I am using the compatible version of Guest Additions with my updated virtual box.  I am baffled as to how my display settings were ruined by this recent update.
